# Remove leading semicolons in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA code that was given to me that will remove a leading semicolon in a given cell in a specific column. However, some of the cells in that column start with 2 or more semicolons. I need to be able to loop through and remove any leading semicolons. ex..  ;;;car;loan;savings;home -  car;loan;savings;home    I want to keep the semicolons in between items....just remove the leading ones. I do not know how to add the proper loop to the code below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

code:

```
   With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
      lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
      With Range("Q2:Q" & lastrow)
       .Value = Evaluate(Replace("IF(LEFT(@,1)="";"",replace(@,1,1,""""),@)", "@", .Address))
      End With
   End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each cell in the range, and then loop through the characters until you get one that is not ";".

```
    Dim cell As Variant
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim mystr As String
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each cell In Range("Q2:Q" & lastrow)
            mystr = cell.Value
            Do Until Left(mystr, 1) <> ";"
                mystr = Right(mystr, Len(mystr) - 1)
            Loop
            cell.Value = mystr
        Next cell
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.Value = Evaluate(Replace("IF(LEFT(@,1)="";"",MID(@,FIND(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(@,"";"",""""),1),@),LEN(@)),@)", "@", .Address))
```

This will take the entire string, identify the first non-semicolon character (delete all semicolons, take the first remaining character on the `LEFT`), then `FIND` where it appears in the original text, and return the entire string from that point onwards.

```
MID(A1, 'Extract from the text
    FIND( 'Starting with
        LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,";",""),1), 'The first non-semicolon character
        A1), 'in the text
    LEN(A1)) 'until the end of the text
```

(N.B. If there are no non-semicolon characters in the string, for example ";;;;;", then the entire string will be returned.  You can add an additional `IF` statement to check `LEN(SUBSTITUTE(@,";",""))>0` if you do not want that result)

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have some text in a cell that might have 2 or more ";" in the start of the string. And you wish to remove them from the cell. This loops through the cell & removes any beginning ";" for you. It then moves down to the next cell & repeats until it encounters an empty cell.

```
Private Sub whatever()

Dim myString As String
myString = Selection.Cells.Value

Do While IsEmpty(Selection.Cells.Value) = False
    Do While Left(myString, 1) = ";"
        Selection.Cells.Value = Right(myString, Len(myString) - 1)
        myString = Selection.Cells.Value
    Loop

    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    myString = Selection.Cells.Value
Loop
```

Comment: `myString = Selection.Cells.Value` - this will fail if more than one cell is selected. That's an automatic type mismatch.

Comment: @BigBen yeah. The way this one works is a single cell is selected. I edited the code so that a person should select the top cell in the column & then it processes the remaining cells in that column.

Comment: How would I make this start at Q2 and go all the way down column Q?

Comment: @ngz in the spreadsheet, click the Q2 cell. Then execute the code.

Comment: @ngz If this has solved your problem, please hit the Tick mark to accept the answer - it will let other people know that there is a solution, if they search for a similar problem!